# How to make a "return" animation between 2 iOS views in a navigation controller?

Tags: ios

How to make a "turn back" animation between 2 iOS views in a navigation controller?

By "turn back" I mean the view turns itself back along a vertical axis. You can see an example in the amazon iOS app when you select a filter for your research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you cannot use navigation controller
You will need to use view controller `presentModalViewController` and set `modalPresentationStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;` in the new view controller you want to present

```
//Create the view
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: I think you meant modalTransitionStyle and not modalPresentationStyle :)